# How to process in Flink stream of keyed and batch events from one Kafka topic

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am tring to write a Flink job to process events from the single Kafka topic. Stream of events contains keyed events and batch events. Keyed events represent Transaction and have key transactionId. These events are translated to insert/update/delete logic, hovewer batch events has no transaction key but described by business conditions that converted to the join with latest state of all computed transactions joined on conditions. Events are coming in the correct order from the topic.

`upsert` - upsert by transactionid
`delete` - delete by transactionid
`paid` -change  all transaction for agent in the lists paystatus to true
`reverse` -change  all transaction for agent in the lists paystatus to false
`publish` - change all transactions with batchid is publish true

| event_id | event_type | event_ts | transaction_id | batch_id | is_published | paiments [(agent, paymentstate)] | agent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `upsert` | 2024-01-02 16:14:02 | 436 | 1 | false | [(1, false),(2, true)] | null |
| 2 | `upsert` | 2024-01-02 16:14:04 | 437 | 1 | false | [(3, false),(4, false)] | null |
| 3 | `upsert` | 2024-01-02 16:14:05 | 436 | 1 | false | [(1, true),(2, false)] | null |
| 4 | `paid` | 2024-01-02 16:14:10 | null | null | null | null | [3] |
| 5 | `reverse` | 2024-01-02 16:14:15 | null | null | null | null | [3] |
| 6 | `publish` | 2024-01-02 16:14:20 | null | 1 | null | null | null |

Comment: A few comments here:

1. I think you'll need to provide more details on how batch events are used (in conjunction with keyed state???), otherwise it's hard for me to figure out what you're trying to do.
2. Once you do a keyBy(), to partition based on the transactionId, the ordering of events can change. So typically you can't depend on order of events from a topic being preserved.
3. I assume events are saved as JSON in the topic, to support mixing keyed and batch events, but it would be good for you to clarify.

Comment: I added examples for the understanding. At the same time, it is a very common condition in the systems when a batch process runs after CRUD events and batch processes set of rows in a current state. A question is how to do it in the correct order using the streaming approach as for this there is a requirement to get near real-time processing. It seems that Flink can do it, do I need to emit checkpoints periodically when a set of crud events are coming together and switch to per-event mode when batch? Do I need to write a state aggregator function where all required events join them with batch?

Answer (score 0):

1. Split your stream into transaction events vs. batch events, via a ProcessFunction with side outputs.
2. Use `.keyBy(transaction id)` to key the transaction events stream.
3. Turn the batch event stream into a broadcast stream.
4. Connect the broadcast stream to the keyed stream.
5. Create a custom `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` that implements the required logic, including the generation of results & clearing of state for transaction events that match the batchId when a publish event is received.

See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/ for details on how to use a broadcast stream in this manner.